# Unit test in Spring Boot common library project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, junit, kotlin

My question is how to configure gradle and spring boot to run the unit test of a common library project without applying `org.springframework.boot` plugin?

I have a Spring boot common library project that is built with `gradle`.
The problem is:

- I don't want to apply `org.springframework.boot` plugin into my project because it should be used for spring boot application but a library project.
- I need to wire (@Autowired) some bean in my tests.
- I have tried to configure my `build.gradle` file as below

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
        junitPlatformVersion = '1.0.0-M2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:${kotlinVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
//apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar {
    baseName = 'my-common-lib'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:$springBootVersion"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude module: 'junit'
    }
    testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: assertjCoreVersion

    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api')
    testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine')
}
```

- My tests as below:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest
class MyCommonLibraryTest(@Autowired val myBean: MyBean) {
  @Test
  ...
}
```

- Finally, I got `BeanCreationException` thrown when running the test

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'anotherBean' defined in class path resource [com/pipedbits/spiralg/templateengine/infrastructure/configuration/TemplateConfiguration.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource not found in classpath: kotlin/coroutines/coroutines.kotlin_builtins
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: The test is related to java reflection. For example, I have set of java class (ClassWhiteList) which is defined in a `@Configuration class ApplicationConfiguration`. `classWhiteList` is fixed and it is necessary when creating instance of `MyBean`. I have function `MyBean.isAllowedClass(String className)` to check if a class is in the white list.